# Ngx-Datatable will not display row data retrieved via Ajax unless mouse over or mouse leave event triggered

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I really do not understand what the issue is with the [Ngx-Datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable%20v15.0). It just will not update and display records until a mouse interaction.

This happens even the first time I bind data.

After the Ajax retrieval of data is complete, the display will not update unless I mouse in or mouse out of the datagrid.

I have tried https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/934

Here is the code:

.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog, MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { AppLoaderService } from 'app/shared/services/app-loader/app-loader.service';
import { TournamentPopupComponent } from './tournament-popup/tournament-popup.component';
import { egretAnimations } from "../../../shared/animations/egret-animations";
import { HttpService } from 'app/shared/services/http.service';
import { Tournament } from 'app/shared/models/tournament.model';
import { DatatableComponent } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.scss'],
  animations: egretAnimations
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('ngxDatatable', { read: null, static: null }) ngxDatatable: DatatableComponent;

  items: any[];

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private loader: AppLoaderService,
    private http: HttpService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTournaments()
  }

  async getTournaments() {
    this.loader.open();
    var result = await this.http.getTournaments();
    this.refreshTableHack(result);
    this.loader.close();
  }

  openPopUp(data: any = {}, isNew?) {
    let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any> = this.dialog.open(TournamentPopupComponent, {
      width: '720px',
      disableClose: true,
      data: { isNew: isNew, payload: data }
    })
    dialogRef.afterClosed()
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (!res) {
          // If user press cancel
          return;
        }
        this.loader.open();

        var tournament = new Tournament();
        tournament.id = res['id'];
        tournament.date = res['date'];
        tournament.name = res['name'];
        tournament.participants = res['participants'];

        var result;

        if (isNew) {
          this.http.addTournament(tournament).then((r) => {
            this.handleAjaxCompletion(r, isNew);
          });
        } else {
          this.http.updateTournament(tournament).then((r) => {
            this.handleAjaxCompletion(r, isNew);
          });
        }

      })
  }

  private async handleAjaxCompletion(res: string, isNew: boolean) {
    var duration = 5000;
    var result = await this.http.getTournaments();
    //this.items = result;
    this.refreshTableHack(result);
    this.loader.close();

    if (res == 'success') {
      this.snackBar.open('Tournament ' + ((isNew) ? 'Added' : 'Updated'), '', {
        duration: duration,
      });
    } else {
      this.snackBar.open(res, null, { duration: duration });
    }
  }

  private refreshTableHack(data) {
    this.items = data;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ngxDatatable.element.click();
    }, 0);
    //this.items = [...data];

  }
}
```

.html template

```html
<div class="m-333">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openPopUp({}, true)">Add Tournament</button>
</div>

<mat-card class="p-0" [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'50px',delay:'300ms'}}">
    <mat-card-content class="p-0">
        <ngx-datatable #ngxDatatable class="material ml-0 mr-0" [rows]="items" [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50"
            [scrollbarH]="true" [limit]="10" [rowHeight]="50">
            <ngx-datatable-column name="Name" [flexGrow]="1">
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{ row?.name }}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column name="Participants" [flexGrow]="1">
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{ row?.participants }}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column name="Date" [flexGrow]="1">
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    {{ row?.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column name="Status" [flexGrow]="1">
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    <mat-chip mat-sm-chip [color]="'primary'" [selected]="row.isActive">
                        {{row.isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'}}</mat-chip>
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column name="Actions" [flexGrow]="1">
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button color="primary" class="mr-1" (click)="openPopUp(row, false)">
                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button color="warn" (click)="deleteItem(row)">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
        </ngx-datatable>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.items = [...this.items];` instead of `this.items = [...data]`?

Comment: Yes I have, that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` and calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

```
constructor(
private dataService: MyDataService
private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
```

) {}

```
this.dataService.subscribe(res => {
    ...
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
});

https://themeforest.net/item/egret-angular-4-material-design-admin-template/20161805/comments?page=25&filter=all#comment_22326113
```